# How do i highlight the expanded group in expandable list view?

Tags: android, xml

I would like to make it so that upon clicking a group in the expandable list view, the expanded group would be highlighted (by applying a stroke aroung the gradient im using for items in the list). Ive tried the following and the list keeps the normal look i made, not the one i made for state_expanded=true.

Relative Layout Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:minHeight="60dip"
                android:background="@drawable/gradients"
                >
```

gradients.xml code:

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_expanded="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#000000"
                android:centerColor="#ffffff"
                android:startColor="#000000"
                android:angle="270"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="#ffa319" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

<item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#000099"
                android:centerColor="#0053cf"
                android:startColor="#000099"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#00007a" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:minHeight="60dip"
                <!-- android:background="@drawable/gradients" -->
                >
```

back ground change in your group name textview tag..

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/groupname"
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:textSize="16px"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:paddingLeft="50px"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@drawable/gradients"/>
```

for more information visit [this link](http://kundanit.blogspot.com/2011/08/android-expandable-list-view.html)